# How to use resource_payer on eosjs

Tags: eosjs

EOSJS added a new feature to their library and now we can specify the resource payer.

I wanted to try and use it but their example doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you setup your own eosio chain to test the feature? None of the public blockchains I am aware of have activated the RESOURCE_PAYER feature on the blockchain side.  (That is none of Jungle, Kylin, EOSIO Testnet, EOS, WAX)

New protocol features are only avalable after feature activation.

Comment: Ah, I see! Sadly, I only do development on the public testnets. Operating on bleeding edge surely is hard, have an awesome day amazing human! :)

Comment: Jungle is likely to be the public EOSIO chain to activate the feature first. Follow updates in the Jungle telegram group https://t.me/jungletestnet, or check http://jungle.eosn.io/ and look for the the RESOURCE_PAYER item.  It will tell you from which block it is activated. (currently not activated)

Answer (score 0):

here is the link: [how to use resource_payer](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/how-to-guides/how-to-set-a-payer)

It's not available on Wax that I had tested!