# Claim rewards system (Something like how alien worlds give rewards to players)

Tags: eosjs, wallet, signing

I'm trying to make something similar to alien worlds, how can I transfer tokens from the contract to the user but have the resource costs go to the user using EOSJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please consult this documentation page, it should answer your question:
https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/latest/features/resource_payer

an alternative is via noops and ONLY_BILL_FIRST_AUTHORIZER upgrade protocol feature.
you can read about it here:
https://cmichel.io/eosio-how-to-pay-for-users-cpu/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

So that's the only way? I have actually read about it and have tried it but the testnet doesn't seem to support it yet. 

I actually asked about the resource payer a few weeks ago: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/6023/how-to-use-resource-payer-on-eosjs and I got to know that testnets do not support this yet so I was wondering how others handled it when resource_payer feature wasn't in yet. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have updated my answer to give the old alternative way

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try it out, have an awesome day, awesome person! :)

Comment: Hi @ovi, I tried your suggestion but what I really wanted was to have the users pay for the cpu and the account in the server will transfer tokens to the user. I have tried reversing it but the problem is that I just can't get to make the signatures work together (I'm using UAL with react). Do you have some suggested resources for this? I've spent around 8+ hours trying to find a solution but I couldn't make it work, sorry for bugging you and thank you again!

Comment: hi @JesseDwight I am not sure I fully understand your problem you try to solve.
I see now you are talking about UAL and client side implementation. you can try to formulate a more elaborate text for your problem and post it in the EOSIO dev telegram channel https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1

Comment: Thank you @ovi, just to give you more context, I want to implement a rewards claiming system where the user would request for claim a transaction and the system's account would initiate the transfer but the client would pay for the cpu. That's what I want to achieve. I've tried the telegram link that you sent but it didn't work so I tried looking for an eosio dev channel on telegram, I found one but not sure if it's the official one but thank you for your awesomeness again. Have an awesome week! :)